# React application not get reloaded on saving new changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, process, formik

We are using React v17 in our project. When we save new changes application is not reloading in browser. Instead a bug appears as `Reference Error: process not defined`. Every time we require to refresh the application in order to view changes. As application is a form based application thus whole form required to fill again to test changes.

Comment: Please upload the code our magical eys are not working for now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced a similar kind of issue. To me following resolution works.

Please run the following commands in project root:

```
npm i --save-dev react-error-overlay@6.0.9
```

Add a line in the resolutions section in package.json as:

```
"resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9"
  }
```

And then run `npx npm-force-resolutions`

Restart react, hot reloading should start working again and `process not defined` error should also not come.

Feel free to comment if face any issues in following instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please include the contents of your package.json file?